# Not getting response on the same page using Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

Hi I am working on a project in which I am using Ajax to display output on the same page. It contains a JSP form that takes user input and store the inputs to the database and in response I want to display a success message.

But I am not getting the message on the same page.

JSP Code:- I have tried using both get and post method but of no use.
On clicking Add button it should display a success message if record inserted successfully on the same page but I am getting the message on another page.

Please help to fix this. This is the first time I am using Ajax. Is there any changes that we need to make to web.XML file?

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

            <head>
            <title>Courses</title>


          <script>
                var request;
                function addDetails(){
                    request=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.onreadystatechange()=getResult();
                    var cid=document.getElementById("cid").value;
                    var name=document.getElementById("name").value;
                    var syllabus=document.getElementById("syllabus").value;
                    var duration=document.getElementById("duration").value;
                    var fees=document.getElementById("fees").value;

                    request.open("get","Courses?cid="+cid,"name="+name,"syllabus="+syllabus,"duration="+duration,"fees="+fees,true);
                    //request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    //request.send(cid&name&syllabus&duration&fees);
                    request.send();
                }

                function getResult(){
                    if(request.readyState===4&&request.status===200){
                        var result=request.responseText();
                        document.getElementbyID("output").innerHTML=result;
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementbyID("output").innerHTML="Error";
                    }

                }



                </script>
                <style>
                body {
                    text-align:center;
                }
                h1 {
                    font-size:30px;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    color:peru;
                }
                pre {

                    font-size:20px;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    color:black;
                }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Course Information</h1><br/>
            <form action="Courses" method="Post">
                <pre>
            Course ID    : <input type="text" name="cid" id="cid" style="width:400px"/><br/>
            Course Name  : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="width:400px"/><br/>
            Syllabus     : <input type="text" name="syllabus" id="syllabus" style="width:400px"/><br/>
            Duration     : <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" style="width:400px"/><br/>
            Fees         : <input type="text" name="fees" id="fees" style="width:400px"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add" onclick="addDetails()"/> <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update"/> <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete"/>
            <p id="output"></p>
                </pre>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

`
Servlet Code:-

```
package ss;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Courses extends HttpServlet {

        protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try{
            String cid=request.getParameter("cid");
            String name=request.getParameter("name");
            String syllabus=request.getParameter("Syllabus");
            String duration=request.getParameter("duration");
            String fees=request.getParameter("fees");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ssi","root","root17");

            if(request.getParameter("Add")!=null){
                String qry="insert into course values(?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(qry);
                ps.setString(1, cid);
                ps.setString(2, name);
                ps.setString(3, syllabus);
                ps.setString(4, duration);
                ps.setString(5, fees);
                int i=ps.executeUpdate();
                   if(i>0){
                       out.println("Registered Successfully");
                   }
                   else{
                       out.println("Registration Fails");
                   }
            }

        if(request.getParameter("Update")!=null){
            String qry="UPDATE course SET Name=?,Duration=?, syllabus=?, fees=? where cid=?";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(qry);
            ps.setString(1,name);
            ps.setString(2,duration);
            ps.setString(3,syllabus);
            ps.setString(4, fees);
            ps.setString(5, cid);
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
                out.println("Updated Successfully");
                out.println(i);

            }
            else{
                out.println("Update fails");
            }
        }
        if(request.getParameter("Delete")!=null){
            String qry="Delete from course where cid=?";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(qry);
            ps.setString(1, cid);
            int i=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(i>0){
                out.println("Record Deleted");
            }
            else{
                out.println("Delete Fails");
            }
        }
       }  
            catch(Exception e){
                out.println(e);
            }

           }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching `addDetails` to a submit button. When it is clicked it will submit the page which you are most likely dont want to happen. Change the type to be just button: `<input type="button" name="Add" value="Add" onclick="addDetails()"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed the type="button" but still no result, now the page also does not refresh.Page remains the same but no output. Is there any mistake I am making while sending data?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and accordingly I made the changes also. Now the page remains the same but still it shows no message.

Comment: Now you are most likely are facing some type of JavaScript issue. First make sure it is calling your servlet. Then start debugging the actual script and make sure it actually gets to the point of updating `ouput` element. You can debug JavaScript in chrome Dev tools or just by putting `alert` calls in there.